# Creating custom spell checking for html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to use some custom functions for spell checking in html inputs? For example I have an input where values are divided by spaces (or commas, doesn't matter) and a function which receives tokens from it. That function decides if token is spelled correctly (in my case there would be some regular expression) and returns true/false value and based on that some words would be underlined. In my head it looks something like this:

```
<input type="text" onCheck="checkToken">

<script>
function checkToken(token) {
  const oneCrazyRegex = /[a-b]/;
  return oneCrazyRegex.test(token);
</script>
```

Or taking whole input:

```
function spellCheckInput(line) {
  // line is an array of tokens
  return line.map(tok => checkToken(tok));
}
```

Is it possible to do with js/css/html or not?

P.S. `onCheck` is example only, I know that this attribute is not valid

Comment: `onCheck`? Please don't use invalid attributes, and avoid using inline `on*` handlers, the same way you (hopefully) don't use inline `style` attributes. JS should go in one place only and that's your script file or tag.

Comment: That just for example, I'll clarify it

Comment: AFAIK there's no native way to *"custom spellcheck underline"* only one word inside an `<input>` field. And you cannot use `<span>` or other tags inside an `<input>` context.

Comment: I think you meant `onchange`, and you are not passing anything to `checkToken` which is expecting `token`.  
Perhaps, pass `this.value`?
Let's say it all works, what is done with the returned value?
Either send it to another element/log to console/alert, Or:
pass `this`,
in the function, `test` `token.value`,
and, instead of `return`, `this.value=`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use regex for cleaning up text but you have to remember that people can fabricate any kind of input they want since the checks would be happening client-side, and anyone can just pop open a console and send anything they want.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you cannot style individual words inside an input, or textarea, element. You can, however, do so inside a general contenteditable element.